# How to get filtered objects only from an array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Schema:

```
var instaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Active: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    Actionusers: [{
        Actiontype: {
            type: Number,
        },
        Iscompleted: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        status: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    }]
})
```

and i have data likewise:

```
_id: 5956020e4f605403d85f24d5,
    Active: 1,
    Actionusers: [{
            Actiontype: 1,
            _id: 5957420f5decd01de09deb3a,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 1,
        },

        {
            Actiontype: 1,
            _id: 5957420f5decd01de09deb3f,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 1,
        },


        {
            Actiontype: 1,
            _id: 5957420f5decd01de09deb44,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 0,
        },


        {
            Actiontype: 1,
            _id: 5957420f5decd01de09deb49,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 0,
        },


        {
            Actiontype: 1,
            _id: 5957420f5decd01de09deb4e,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 0,
        },
    ]
```

i wants list of objects with `status: true` and `Iscompleted: 0`
I am using following query but cant able to get only require data..

```
Model.find({ _id: "5956020e4f605403d85f24d5" },
                 { Actionusers: { $elemMatch: { Iscompleted: 1, status: true } } }).select({Actionusers:1})
```

Comment: `$elemMatch` and standard projection match **"one"** item only. [See the answers to the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) containing `$filter` for "multiple" matches.

Comment: HI @Neil, I just used $filter but no luck to get desired data...can you please help me out ?`.aggregate([
    
    { $match: { 'Actionusers.Iscompleted': 0 } },
    {
        $project: {
            Actionusers: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$Actionusers',
                    as: 'shape',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$shape.Iscompleted', 0] }
                }
            },
            _id: '5956020e4f605403d85f24d5'
        }
    }
    ])`

Comment: You need [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) for the two conditions. `cond: { $and: [ { $eq: ['$$shape.Iscompleted', 0] }, '$$shape.status' ] }`

Comment: Hey man, still its returning to me whole array. what i am doing wrong ?